# Can Unpublishing an app make my account to comply policy

Tags: android, google-play-console

I got an old app which requires the permission of read call logs. Recently, Google do not want the developers to use, they can change their policy. I lost the my key to sign the app. So I cannot update the app.
Does anyone know unpublishing an app make my account to comply policy?
I don't want to get my developer account are banned because of an old app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [App store questions are off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/295004) and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: I tried to ask Google, but I have not a confirmed answer. I wish to know whether anyone was in a similar situation before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will help you avoid getting emails from Google Play if you unpublish your application from the Play Store Console. However, since there are users using the application already, you cannot delete the app completely.

In your case since you lost the Keystore file, there is no choice either. If you get an email saying there is a problem / even if your account is temporarily suspended in a later stage, the email will also contain a link to appeal your claim regarding wrongly suspended action where you can explain your situation.

Mostly, 99% it won't happen and even if it happens, you can explain to them that time. So, unpublish and leave your worries from now.

Hope this helps.